# Hibernate include Stored proc in schema export

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping

I've created a stored procedure in my MySQL database and I want a way to have hibernate include the proc when I run org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport to dump my hibernate configuration into a sql file. I added a mapping file to my hibernate configuration with the proc, but it doesn't add it to the generated sql file when I run a schema export,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <sql-query name="MyProc">
    <return-scalar column="date" type="date"/>
    <return-scalar column="result1" type="float"/>
    <return-scalar column="result2" type="float"/>
    <![CDATA[CALL MyProc(:param1, :param2, :param3)]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What am I doing wrong? Do i need to put the contents of the proc in the hibernate mapping?